# BigQuery: Extraer fecha y año

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

Tengo esta consulta en BIGQUERY:

```
SELECT mes, anio
FROM `Proyect.bd_1.table_1`
GROUP BY mes, anio
ORDER BY mes DESC, anio DESC;
```

Pero el resultado que tengo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tomando en cuenta que el mes en un String en la base de datos..¿como hago para que quede todo en forma secuencia por mes y por año?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, a que te refieres con el objetivo de que  quede todo en forma secuencia por mes y por año?, Puedes mostrar un  ejemplo de cual es el resultado esperado. Por favor

Comment: Buenas. Es decir que quedé de los meses en orden por año: JUL 2022, AGO 2022, SEPT 2022, OCT 2022 y así consecutivamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy bien, Para ordenar los registros en BigQuery por el mes en orden cronológico, puedes utilizar la función ORDER BY en tu consulta. Asumiré que la columna "mes" es de tipo STRING y contiene nombres de meses de forma desordenada.Asi que para lograr el orden adecuado, puedes usar la función CASE para asignar un número a cada mes y luego ordenar por ese número. Te comparto un ejemplo de como quedaria:

```
SELECT mes, anio
FROM `Proyect.bd_1.table_1`
ORDER BY anio desc,
  CASE
    WHEN mes = 'Enero' THEN 1
    WHEN mes = 'Febrero' THEN 2
    WHEN mes = 'Marzo' THEN 3
    WHEN mes = 'Abril' THEN 4
    WHEN mes = 'Mayo' THEN 5
    WHEN mes = 'Junio' THEN 6
    WHEN mes = 'Julio' THEN 7
    WHEN mes = 'Agosto' THEN 8
    WHEN mes = 'Septiembre' THEN 9
    WHEN mes = 'Octubre' THEN 10
    WHEN mes = 'Noviembre' THEN 11
    WHEN mes = 'Diciembre' THEN 12
    ELSE 0
  END;
```

Con este query deberia ordenar por anio(desc) y aparte para mes hace lo siguiente;

1. Asigna un número a cada mes basado en su nombre
2. Luego ordena los registros en función de esos números.

Los meses no reconocidos se asignan al número 0. Esto debería devolverte los registros ordenados cronológicamente por mes.

Saludos